# How to create a custom popup_from_lov field with the "inline" option?

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex21.2

So, I'm currently working on a page function that requires me to create several separate little boxes, each of them being empty at first, and then requiring a selection of data in an popup_from_lov item that will then fill the box with data derived from the picked info. Here's how it looks:

[image]

The item in this case opens up a small modal page that has the data to be selected. The question now is, the same item and function exists in Oracle APEX, and it has an option to choose between "modal dialog" and "inline". Is there a way to set this in the parameters given to the item?

I've tried something like this to no success so far, and sadly, the Oracle documentation doesn't state whether this is possible or not.

[image]

I've tried adding several manners of "inline" option in the "p_attributes" parameters, and a few others, but they've either done nothing or returned an error, because they're not supposed to receive this kind of input.

Comment: apex_item isn't very flexible in a UI... do you really need apex_item ? Can't you code your form using regular page items ?

Comment: Normally I'd prefer using a proper regular page item, but I need to generate these boxes via htp.p functions in PLSQL. I'm not sure whether I can create normal items inside of the html code created in a procedure.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - only apex_item allows for programmatically creating page items. But they don't look good...

Comment: Not a big fan myself either. If anything I just wish the documentation was better. I assume that the "inline" setting could work is in the p_attributes parameter, but the documentation has not a single example of what can be input there. I'll keep looking into it and testing.